# question regarding double summations

Tags: nt.number-theory

I'm looking for a reference and/or table for double summations. The sum I'm trying to compute is

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{km(ak^2+bm^2)}$$ for real numbers $a$, $b$.

Comment: Closed form formula is, probably, out of question. What do you really want to know about that sum?

Comment: Can you do the special case $a=b=1$ in closed form?  If not, then the general case is (of course) hopeless.

Answer (score -1):

You need not any tables to this end. Mathematica does the job by

```
f[a_, b_] := NSum[1/(k*n*(a*k^2 + b*n^2)), {k, 1, Infinity}, {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

For example,

```
f[Pi,0.1]
```

$0.944319 $

I have strong doubts concerning a closed-form expression for this sum.

Comment: I think OP *is* looking for closed-form expressions. Evaluating them numerically is easy to do in any programming language.

Comment: @Federico Poloni: Can you present something constructive? Both Maple and Mathematica fail with it.

Comment: No --- I can't answer the question, I'm just pointing out that yours isn't (probably) the answer OP is looking for, and that "you need not any tables" is a very misleading statement.